# Displaying a recently uploaded file with an image and a link to the file

Tags: php, html, loops

I currently have 5 images on my site and each of these is linked to a file, I have recently added an option to upload a file to the directory "uploads", but I would like for these to be echoed on the site with an image (I have a folder of images named numerically).

Is it possible to create a loop to check if file has been added to a specific directory, e.g. "folder/file.doc"?

I don't have any code for this and I don't expect anyone to code it for me, but if you could please point me in the right direction as to how to make this.

Comment: There [PHP `scandir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) function might come in handy :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe this could help? You just need to read the folder and iterate over all the content while echoing all files with name, link and  tag:

```
if ($handle = opendir('/path/to/your/files')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        echo "<img src='$entry'/><br/>";
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

And this is the corresponding link:

http://php.net/manual/de/function.readdir.php#example-2478